# Regular Expression for one of two phone number formats

Tags: java, ruby, regex

I only want to match either of these formats:

```
(444) 444-4444

444-444-4444
```

Here are two expressions that get close:

```
((?:(\(\d{3}\)\s)|(\d{3}-))\d{3}-\d{4})

((\(\d{3}\)\s)|(\d{3}-))\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Both are saying, use either `(###)` or `###-` and then add `###-####`

The problem is that both examples match `(###-###-####` and other patterns that happen to contain one of my desired strings.

How can I ensure that *only* the exact string matches?

I've seen some examples with carets in the beginning, but I haven't gotten that to work. I'm working in ruby. Thank you.

Comment: Use `\A` to match the start of the string, and `\z` to match the very end of the string (or `\Z` to match the end of the string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input = ['(444) 444-4444', '444-444-4444', '444 444-4444']
input.grep /\A(\(\d{3}\) |\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}\z/
#⇒ [
#   [0] "(444) 444-4444",
#   [1] "444-444-4444"
#  ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. May I ask why you didn't have to specify the empty space `\s` after `\(\d{3}\)`? It's sufficient to just leave an empty space? I'm still learning. I don't have enough cred to vote, but I choose this as the answer.

Comment: In this particular context just an empty space and `\s` do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Pn (444) 444-4444 : " + validatePhoneNumber("(444) 444-4444"));
    System.out.println("Pn 444-444-4444 : " + validatePhoneNumber("444-444-4444"));
}

private static boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
    if (phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) {
        return true;
    } else return phoneNo.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(((\(){1}(\d){3}(\){1}))(\ )(\d){3}(\-)(\d){4}|((\d){3}(\-)(\d){3}(\-)(\d){4}))/gm
```

use this regular expression, I've tested it and it works for both formats

You can use this website for further testing
http://www.regextester.com/6

Comment: When I test this, it still matches other formats. Such as: `(444)-444-4444`
`(444-444-4444`

Comment: hmm. re-edited my answer
now fits for: 
(444) 444-4444
444-444-4444